# Remove <p> tag in php file to interpret html code in vehicle_overview

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm a beginner with wordpress and code.
I'd like to show *vehicle_overview* with html view. 
I can see that is between *p* tags, when I remove *strip_tags* from line
*echo "p class=\"vehicle_overview\">" . strip_tags($post_content) . "/p";*
text color are showing but not *spam* and *br* tags.
Thank you in advanced for your help.

```
$limit        = (isset($lwp_options['vehicle_overview_listings_limit']) && !empty($lwp_options['vehicle_overview_listings_limit']) ? $lwp_options['vehicle_overview_listings_limit'] : 250);
$ellipsis     = (isset($lwp_options['vehicle_overview_ellipsis']) ? $lwp_options['vehicle_overview_ellipsis'] : "[...]");
$stripp       = "<br><p><b><u><i><span><a><img>";

$vehicle_excerpt  = get_post_field("post_excerpt", $id);
$vehicle_overview = get_post_field("post_content", $id);

$vehicle_desc     = (!empty($vehicle_excerpt) ? $vehicle_excerpt : $vehicle_overview);

if($visual_composer_used){
    $post_content = preg_replace( '/\[[^\]]+\]/', '', $vehicle_desc );
    $post_content = substr(strip_tags($post_content, $stripp), 0, $limit) . " " . (strlen(strip_tags($post_content, $stripp)) > $limit ? $ellipsis : "");
} else {
    $post_content = substr(strip_tags($vehicle_desc, $stripp), 0, $limit) . " " . (strlen(strip_tags($vehicle_desc, $stripp)) > $limit ? $ellipsis : "");
}

echo "<p class=\"vehicle_overview\">" . strip_tags($post_content) . "</p>";
} else {
    $listing_details = $Listing->get_use_on_listing_categories();
    $use_on_listing_values = array();
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you correctly but strip_tags without a second parameter (like `$stripp` as you used earlier on) will remove all tags.

Comment: How can I remove <p> tag to show $post_content with html formating?

Comment: I am finding it difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve. By using `$stripp` you are keeping `<p>` tags, without it, you are not...

Comment: I want to add <h2> <br> and others tags to my text, but I can't because is <p> format. Sorry about my English.

Comment: Can you post the result of: `echo strip_tags($post_content);` please.

Comment: The text loose html format like <br>

Comment: I'm sorry, we seem to be having communication issues. I'm out.

Comment: the most straight forward way would be to remove the p tags when you edit post. Why not do that? Btw, the 2nd param of strip_tags means allowable tags. So at the first strip_tags you included <p> in the param and then on the 2nd strip_tags, you didnt pass in any tags..